# Interior, exterior and boundary points in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm currently taking a class on multivariable calculus. The textbook begins by defining interior, exterior and boundary points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and states that, given a set $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, every point $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is either an interior, exterior or boundary point of $M$.

I recognize this must be true for $n = 1, 2, 3$ for geometric reasons but fail to see why it holds in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n>3$. I tried proving it using the definitions of interior, exterior and boundary points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but got nowhere.

Comment: Just wondering, what could the point be other than the 3 options, interior, exterior or boundary?

Comment: Strange as the definitions are independent from the dimension. Hence the proves are valid whatever the dimension is. What definitions are you using for interior, exterior and boundary?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I'm guessing the standardized ones. $\mathbf{a}$ is an interior point of $M$ if there is an open ball centered at $\mathbf{a}$ that lies entirely within $M$; $\mathbf{a}$ is an exterior point of $M$ if there is an open ball centered around $\mathbf{a}$ that lies entirely within the complement $\complement M$ of $M$; $\mathbf{a}$ is a boundary point of $M$ if every open ball centered at $\mathbf{a}$ contains points from both $M$ and $\complement M$.

Comment: Your definitions look good, and are independent from the dimension. You just need to remind what is an open ball in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious. I'll have another go at it.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I still don't see why. What does the proof come down to?

Comment: Can you apply the definition for an interior point using an open ball?